# Extract css and match with data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following scenario:

```
<body class="theme-blue nav-black">
  <a href="#" data-class="theme-blue">Blue theme </a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-black">Dark Nav</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-white">Light Nav</a>
</body>
```

Trying to write a script to match the classes from  and for each matching 'data-class' to add a class "active" to the  element;

Whats the best way to go about doing this?

So the result should look like:

```
<body class="theme-blue nav-black">
  <a href="#" data-class="theme-blue" class="active">Blue theme </a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-black" class="active">Dark Nav</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-white">Light Nav</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using jQuery**

Get the classes from the body, split, map to an array of data attribute strings, and join. Add the class `active` to all selected elements:

```js
var classNames = $('body')
  .attr("class")
  .split(' ')
  .map(function(c) {
    return '[data-class="' +  c + '"]';
  })
  .join(',');
  
$(classNames).addClass('active');

console.log(classNames);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="theme-blue nav-black">
  <a href="#" data-class="theme-blue">Blue theme </a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-black">Dark Nav</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-white">Light Nav</a>
</body>
```

**Without jQuery:**

Get the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) from the body, and convert it to a string query by casting the classList to an array using Array#slice, mapping the classes to data attributes strings, and joining with a comma.
Then use [Document#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Iterate the nodeList with [NodeList#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), and add the `active` class to each node.

```js
var classNames = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('body').classList, 0).map(function(c) {
  return '[data-class="' +  c + '"]';
}).join(',');

document.querySelectorAll(classNames).forEach(function(node) {
  node.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="theme-blue nav-black">
  <a href="#" data-class="theme-blue">Blue theme </a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-black">Dark Nav</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-white">Light Nav</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, I used your one as it was more clear to use. BTW if I wanted to extend it, and do a check to remove the "active" class for those that don't match the data-class, where do I add the if statement?

Comment: You can do the old `$('.active').removeClass('active')` before setting the '.active' class with my code. Or use @NenadVracar's solution, which contains an `if` clause, by adding an `else` clause to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop each `a` element and then use `hasClass()` to check if `body` has the same class and if it does use `addClass()`

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass($(this).data('class'))) {
    $(this).addClass('active')
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="theme-blue nav-black">
  <a href="#" data-class="theme-blue">Blue theme </a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-black">Dark Nav</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-white">Light Nav</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var bodyClass=$("div").attr("class").split(" ");
$.map( bodyClass, function( val, i ) {
    $("a[data-class='"+val+"']").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theme-blue nav-black">
  <a href="#" data-class="theme-blue" >Blue theme </a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-black" >Dark Nav</a>
  <a href="#" data-class="nav-white">Light Nav</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to filter through an array list instead of doing $.each